# ntQuerySystemInformtion and it's struct - size not mismatch and other doubts

Tags: c++, c, windows, debugging, winapi

I'm curious why the API ntquerysysteminformtion return size that is different from the sum of all nextEntryOffsets. I call the API with a SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION structure, and it returns the size of the struct populated as expected.

However if I loop into all entries and sum the NextEntryOffset and do a comparison with the size returned with the API it never mismatch.

```
//call to API

int sum = 0;
pCurrent = nullptr;
pfw = (_SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION*)si;

do {

            pCurrent = pfw;
            pfw = (_SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION*)((PUCHAR)pCurrent + pfw->NextEntryOffset);

           sum += pCurrent->NextEntryOffset;

} while (pCurrent->NextEntryOffset != 0);
```

If I print the value of sum variable and length returned by API they are always not equal.

How to discover / calculate the correct size of each entry if there is no field on the structure for this? My guess is that it's not working because on the last entry the NextEntryOffset is null, but this is weird, because I dont see a way to calculate the real size of each entry without just believe on the returned length. I guess that there is a way, right?

I was reading unofficial documentation and it describe that the **start of its output buffer and irregularly throughout the buffer when given specific information classes like mine**. I don't understand how it work, but I assume that for example if there is an pointer to another structure this pointer size + the size of the data or other struct pointed is calculated as part of the total size which may be dynamically, correct?

I also tried see if the field offsets works as expected on this unoffical documentation, but I failed to access it contents. It work for example to see the supposed address of UniqueProcessId, however I can't find a way to see the value inside this address to confirm.

```
PVOID tmp = pCurrent + 0x50;
wprintf(L"ID: %d", *tmp);
```

It fails. I can call the structure like pCurrent.UniqueProcessId and it works. But how to move on the data without depends on the struct? Examples codes are very welcome.

Thank so much.

Answer (score 0):

The loop looks correct. The size doesn't match because you can't measure the size of the last struct in the return buffer that way. What's going on is the structure is variable length. In modern C we would declare the last element as a flexible array of SYSTEM_THREAD_ENTRY (where the size is given in NumberOfThreads), but the stuff from NTDLL is old.

The "right" way to code it (in so far as there's any right) is to copy the data you need into your own datastructure then discard the original buffer.

Comment: Thanks Joshua for quick answer, really appreciated. I was not aware of this structure. It's funny, I don't have this SYSTEM_THREAD_ENTRY on my declaration, I was using one found on the internet (from react OS?). However I have number of threads, but it don't have members. I'm not sure where I failed, if on the struct definition or if I need to do some manual sum with number of threads and imagename since both appears to be variable. Do you mind in provide a working example where the size match? :)

Comment: Sorry for dumb questions. If I understood it properly, when I call the API I'm not manipulating the real data, it's just a copy returned for my use, not? Just to understand and improve my skills related with the copy the data and discard the original. I mean, even if I break all the structure I will just affect my own app because the original structure was never sent to me, am I correct?

Comment: So to find out the proper size I should do my sum as I was doing + pCurrent.numberofthreads * sizeof (struct SYSTEM_THREAD_ENTRY) in each entry?

Comment: @albfrk99: I don't think you can do that. The API is allowed to return a datastructure that has holes in it.

Answer (score 0):

The `sum` you get only calculates the length of the first to penultimate struct, which is not include the length of the last one. As other answer pointed out, this is a variable-length struct, Each struct is immediately followed in memory by one or more [`SYSTEM_THREAD_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntquerysysteminformation#system_thread_information) structures that provide info for each thread in the preceding process.

And there is also the memory space for the `ImageName.Buffer`(the size is determined by the system), you do not need to calculate the size of each struct yourself, first pass `NULL` to get the required size:

```
NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, NULL, 0, &length);
```

If you want to know the size of the last structure, just use `length-sum`.

In addition, `pCurrent + 0x50` is equal to `&pCurrent[0x50]`, try to test wih `(char*)pCurrent + 0x50`.

For variable arrays, see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040826-00/?p=38043

Comment: Thank you Drake Wu - MSFT. I understand, it's not possible to calculate the struct size this way. You told about call the API passing second param as NULL and it will return size to allocate, but what if on the second call a new process was created and the size increased? Or the API guarantee the copy of process at that time?

About access the contents without the structure it failed. I'm able to access all them via members of the struct and the memory address as pCurrent+offset, but no matter what I do with (char *) or similar things the contents is never correct.